# Azure Service Bus queues - peeking messages for debugging BEFORE consumer grabs it?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Given an ASB queue, and an existing subscriber. If I want to use a tool (eg. [Azure Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer)) to peek messages that get put onto the queue for debugging purposes (just so I can check the message is as expected) - how can I do this before the existing subscriber grabs the message? Presumably it's always going to be a race to who gets it first - the subscriber (which might be in prod, so I don't want to stop it), and me trying to peek the message in Azure Service Bus Explorer.

I know I could use topics, and create a temporary subscription for ASB Explorer - but that requires a higher paid-for tier of ASB.

Is there any way to do this with just queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it. You are introducing competing consumers into the mix and will spend more time (read money) than saving. Not to mention the complications that will be introduced into the solution.

Sit down, review the costs associated with a Standard tier option and compare it with the option of coming up with a creative solution based on you pay rate. Hands down you'll find the first option more appealing. A classic build vs buy.

Comment: Thanks. I'd assumed this was the case - but just wanted to check I wasn't missing knowledge of some functionality that allowed it for this particular "diagnostic/debug" use-case (seems like it would be quite a common one). To be honest, this is more a "nice to have". For this particular client, I know it's better to not have this functionality at all, than to pay for standard tier for each of their environments. I'm not using queues _that_ heavily in this project anyway.

Comment: Fair enough. The Standard tier is not as expensive as folks think. First, you don't pay for each namespace you provision. You pay for actual namespace as much as you'd pay if you'd provision dozens. It's transactions (messages) for each namespace that are charged. And even that is pennies. So $10 per N number of standard namespaces and likely less than that for the messages and have at it with topics/subscriptions and a bunch of other messaging features and not just basic queueing.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. So if I create two service bus instances (namespaces), I only pay for one? What scope do they need to be in for them to share the same base cost? Is it just any instance in the same subscription scope? Do you have a link to any documentation on this?
I'll have 3 environments for this particular client, so I was thinking that the base cost would be £7.50 per environment - so £270 per year extra. But if it's just £90 per year extra, then this is more feasible. I have a resource group per environment.

Comment: It's documented poorly here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/service-bus/. It says "1,000 brokered connections are included with the standard messaging tier (via the base charge) and can be shared across all queues, topics, subscriptions and event hubs within the associated Azure subscription." Operations charged per namespace, basic charge is on the subscription. I happened to have many clients on ASB to find this out.

Comment: Thank you - that's very useful to know. Strange that they've hidden away that bit of info. In that case, if they're only paying one base charge across all their environments, that's now a good option.

Comment: I don't think they hide it intentionally. It has always been like that. And the focus on Premium so little details get lost in between. Standard is great for development and testing, price wise is affordable and can serve as many devs as necessary under a single subscription. Production is a different story. Cheers!

Comment: I don't think they hide it intentionally. It has always been like that. And the focus on Premium so little details get lost in between. Standard is great for development and testing, price wise is affordable and can serve as many devs as necessary under a single subscription. Production is a different story. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this with just queues?

Not sure if this would make sense from the business point of view but technically it is possible.

What you have to do is when you send the messages to the queue, you will need to defer those messages by some time. A deferred message cannot be fetched by subscribers in "peek-lock" mode but you can always fetch those messages in "peek" mode.

Comment: I wouldn't want to ongoingly add delays to all messages being processed just for this use-case. Sounds like what I want isn't possible. It's a shame that using topics means I need to move to the next ASB tier, as that would be the perfect solution.

Comment: I agree with you.